# Subscribe in angular2

Tags: angular, http, angular2-services

In my project i have a service call that i use in multiple components.Is there any way to have a separate method in the service to save the data and call that method to get the data.The first method below is the service call to get a reusable data and the second method is the one that i call to get that data.But it returns undefined each time i use it.Help please!!!

```js
 GetUserRoles(): Observable<LoggedInUserDetails> {
    return this.http.get(BaseUrl + GetUserRole).map((res: Response) => {
      var data = res.json();
      this.loggedInUser = data;
      return this.loggedInUser;
    }) 
  }



 getUserDetails() {
    return this.loggedInUser;
  }
```

component using the above methods

```
export class IntiatedTravelSummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  public loggedInUser: LoggedInUserDetails;
  public id:number
  intiatedTravelRequestDetail: TravelReqForm;
  test:TravelReqForm[];
  test2:TravelReqForm[];
  constructor(private neuTravelService: NeuTravelService,private route:ActivatedRoute) {
   this.id =route.snapshot.params['TravellerId'];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser =this.neuTravelService.getUserDetails();
      this.neuTravelService.GetIntiatedTravelDetails(this.loggedInUser).subscribe(data =>{ this.test = data;
  this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail= this.neuTravelService.getTravelSummaryDetails(this.id,this.test);
   console.log(this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail);
       });
     }
}
```

Update* 
or if anyone can tell me how to pass data synchronously to the view.
i.e this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail shows a value within the service call but shows undefined after the call.
If anyone can tell me how to render the view after the data is loaded

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.neuTravelService.GetUserRoles().subscribe(data => {
          this.loggedInUser = data;
          this.neuTravelService.GetIntiatedTravelDetails(this.loggedInUser).subscribe(data =>{ this.test = data;
      this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail= this.neuTravelService.getTravelSummaryDetails(this.id,this.test);
       console.log(this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail);
           });
        });
        console.log(this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail);

         }
    }
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to an observable in order to make the request. Right now you are not making any requests.

Comment: i am subscribing in my other components

Comment: Can you add your code where you subscribe to this method and your usage on `loggedInUser` inside that?

Comment: sure ive updated my question please check

Comment: Is `this.loggedInUser` is assigned to something in `ngOnInit` by the time you call it?

Comment: no its undefined

Comment: but it is working well under other components

Comment: And why do you think it shouldn't be undefined?

Comment: because it should be assigned value returned by the getUserRoles method which is called before

Comment: Where do you provide `NeuTravelService` ? Are you sure this component is using the same instance with other components?

Comment: yes it does ....and where do you provide neutravel servicce in the sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed the `intiatedTravelRequestDetail` is undefined outside the callback, here is an excellent answer for you, written by our good sir Mr. @echonax :) : **[How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)**

This asynchronous event also causes that the view is rendered before data has been retrieved. Since you are not providing a sample of your template, I'm guessing that `this.intiatedTravelRequestDetail` is an object and you want to display properties from this.

You could use the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator), i.e `?`

```html
{{intiatedTravelRequestDetail?.myProperty}}
```

This safeguards null values.

Also you could wrap it it inside a `*ngIf`

```html
<div *ngIf="intiatedTravelRequestDetail">
  {{intiatedTravelRequestDetail.myProperty}}
</div>
```

which won't render that part of the view unless there is values in `intiatedTravelRequestDetail`.

Hope this helps! :)